# How to delay an observable in Angular 6 / Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following method `GetCurrentUserDelayedTest` that i wanted to put a delay on. I have left the original implementation here `GetCurrentUser` to demonstrate how i was originally using it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../models/user';

export class UserService {

    // Normal method without delay
    public GetCurrentUser(): Observable<User>
    {
        return of(new User(""));
    }

    // Method with delay attempt at code
    public GetCurrentUserDelayedTest(): Observable<User>
    {
        var observable = new Observable<User>((observable) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                return observable.complete();
            }, 2000);
        });

        observable.subscribe(() => {
            return of(new User(""));
        });

        return observable;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to delay the method from returning its data by 2 seconds.

What am i doing wrong? I'm brand new to angular 6 and typescript.

I'm calling it like this:

```
this.userService.GetCurrentUserDelayedTest()
    .subscribe((currentUser) => {
        this.loadingGameState = false;
    });
```

The "Loading App" part remains on screen (no errors are thrown) rather than updating the view to show "Welcome"

```
<div *ngIf="loadingGameState">Loading App</div>
<div *ngIf="!loadingGameState">
  Welcome
</div>
```

**Edit:**

[image]

Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.
  Type 'Promise' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable): Observable'.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use [delay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delay) function

```
public GetCurrentUserDelayedTest(): Observable<User>
{
    return of(new User(""))
       .pipe(delay(2000));
}
```

Comment: Argument of type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<User, User>'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<User>): Observable<User>'.

Comment: do you import `delay` from 'rxjs/operators'?

Comment: I don't seem to have that choice in my import quick actions (VsCode)

Comment: Ah, well... adding it works, thanks man. where can i find out how to do this thing in the future? is there source for this, i struggled to find such a thing :)

Comment: you can check this page http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#categorized

Answer (score 4):

A more detailed example using HttpClient:

```
of(null).pipe(
  delay(2000),
  flatMap(() => {
    return this.http.post<any>(url, params);
  })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mznw5m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser.service.ts

Use in the declaration of the `Observable` `observable.next()` so you can trigger the subscribers.

Comment: Ahhh, good to know what was wrong with my initial implementation. Thanks!

Comment: the link is broken